# How to maintain the authentication within SecurityContext after application restart?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Other than using J2EE `preauthentication`, I put authentication management in a custom pojo class:

```
public boolean grantAuthentication(UserRole role) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    if(role.equals(UserRole.ROLE_ADMIN)){
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserRole.ROLE_ADMIN.toString()));
    }
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserRole.ROLE_USER.toString()));

    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(),
            authorities);

    user.setAuthorities(authorities);
            // here the authentication inject into SecurityContext
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    return true;
}
```

Above class is within the `controller` class that handling user login form from the login page.

But if user gets in the middle of something, like /order/view and then restart the application, and refresh the page, the there is an exception complaining about:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot obtain authentication object in security context at this time
Cannot obtain authentication object in security context at this time
```

So is there anyway to maintain the authentication object in the session or something, or do i have to redirect user back to the login page? if so, then how can I put user back to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

If you add spring session management it will be handled automatically.Add session management in springsecurity.xml as like this,

```
<security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/jsp/general/sessionTimeout.html" />
```